# Интерпретатор Scheme для линукса

Tags: lisp, scheme

Посоветуйте интерпретатор Scheme для линукса. Хочу, чтобы он был с REPL, с возможностью вернуться стрелкой вверх к предыдущему выражению и отредактировать в нем любое место, а не только последнюю строку. Чтобы скрипты .scm можно было запускать из консоли как обычные программы и получать на экране ответ. Предложений много, не знаю, что выбрать.

Comment: Cвязанный вопрос: [What is the closest thing to Slime for Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/110911/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Для Linux и встраивания, сейчас уже однозначно - [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/).

С целью писать в продакшен для платформ, в т.ч. мобильных - [Gambit](https://github.com/feeley/gambit).

У [Chicken](https://www.call-cc.org/)  комьюнити а-ля AUR, соответственно - толковая организация модулей и хорошая поддержка.

Когда нет возможности использовать [EMACS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), и с целью обучения в качественной среде, подходит [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/).

Практичный инструмент для всего, что можно назвать сценариями - [SCSH](https://scsh.net/).

Answer (score 2):

[Geiser в Emacs](http://nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_3.html#The-REPL) поддерживает [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) и [CHICKEN Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) <sup>(из [@haziz ответа на связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28998868/4279))</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая альтернатива - Chez Scheme. У него есть встроенный редактор s-выражений (expedit), быстрая VM и дополнение названий симболов.